# How to add a custom block in Magento 2 System Configuration Group?

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-config

I am trying to add a text block in `Magento 2` system configuration group.
I want to write some hints for the users in a separate group. As it can be done in `Magento 1`.

Here is my screenshot what I actually want.

[image: Magento 1.x System Configuration Group's Block]

Still, I am waiting for any response. Is there anyone who has done this before in Magento 2?
Please let me know about this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Anyone found solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<frontend_model>` feature of `system configuration`. here is the example

```
     <field id="YOUR_NAME" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" sortOrder="100">
             <frontend_model>VENDOR\MODULE_NAME\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Advanced</frontend_model>
             <attribute type="shared">1</attribute>
     </field>
```

and your `block` file should contain this code

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE_NAME\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

class Advanced extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * Template path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'system/config/advance/YOUR_FILE.phtml';

    /**
     * Render fieldset html
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $columns = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') ? 5 : 4;
        return $this->_decorateRowHtml($element, "<td colspan='{$columns}'>" . $this->toHtml() . '</td>');
    }
}
```

And in your `view\adminhtml\templates\system\config\advance\YOUR_FILE.phtml` file you can write anything which you want

```
<div>
<?php echo __('Hello WOrld'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where to keep this phtml file.

Comment: view\adminhtml\templates\system\config\advance\YOUR_FILE.phtml

Comment: Any reason @GauravAgrawal :)

Comment: Hey Keyur, I am not able to check your answer after implementation. because of some access issue. So whenever I will check and complete it. Will update here.

Comment: Hey Keyur, I have tried your solution today. And it not worked for me. It shows a black page after adding code provided by you.

Comment: Then there must be something in log, please check it, might be some syntax error @GauravAgrawal

Comment: I have checked the log, but I didn't find anything in it.

Comment: I also tried it and it gives me invalid template error.  For me the paths are declared as `protected $_template = 'system/config/userguide/info.phtml';` and `view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/userguide/info.pht‌​ml`

Comment: I figured it out, in my case during FTP upload the filename got corrupted so it couldn't find the block template file.