# Magento 2 toggle switch (yes/no) in admin config of custom module using system.xml or in any programmatic way

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-config

I understand that **we can create a toggle switch using form with ui_component**. However, I want to **create an admin configuration for my custom module using system.xml configuration**.

> Is there any way to apply the **toogle switch (yes/no)** (which is a ui_component of magento, to **system.xml** configuration? 
>   I want it to be implemented instead of a select type with dropdown option.

reference: [Magento 2 form field toggled type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/magento-2-form-field-toggled-type)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After several research, I come up with this solution. (Not a clean code but still able to come up with the expected results)

I ended up creating a block to be inserted in the admin system config using the **`<frontend_model/> markers`** [reference here](https://magently.com/blog/magento-2-backend-configuration-frontend-model-part-33/)

First, I added a **`Field`** inside **`system.xml`** config file. It goes like this:

```
<field id="status" type="checkbox" translate="label" sortOrder="104" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Advanced</frontend_model>
    <attribute type="shared">1</attribute>
</field>
```

**`Block file`** which is the **`class Advanced`** code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

class Advanced extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
/**
 * Template path
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_template = 'system/config/advance/check.phtml';

/**
 * Render fieldset html
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
 * @return string
 */
public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
{
    //$columns = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') ? 5 : 4;
    return $this->_decorateRowHtml($element, "<td class='label'>Label Text</td><td>" . $this->toHtml() . '</td><td></td>');
}
}
```

**`check.phtml`** code the **`phtml file`**

```
<style>
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 37px;
    height: 22px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.switch input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.sliderOne {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    left: -7.75px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.sliderOne:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    left: .5px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #79a22e;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #2196F3;

}

input:checked + .sliderOne {
    background-color: #79a22e;
}

input:focus + .sliderOne {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #2196F3;

}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
    transform: translateX(22px);

}
input:checked + .sliderOne:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(22px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(22px);
    transform: translateX(22px);

}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 35px;

}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}

.sliderOne.round {
    border-radius: 35px;

}

.sliderOne.round:before {
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

}

</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {

    if(document.getElementById('spa').classList.contains("slider")) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("slider")[0].setAttribute("class","sliderOne round");
        document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML = "  &nbsp; No";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName("sliderOne")[0].setAttribute("class","slider round");
        document.getElementById('toggle').innerHTML = "  &nbsp; Yes";
    }
}
</script>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()" checked>
    <span class="slider round" id="spa"></span>
</label>
<span id="toggle"></span>
```

[Main reference for the whole idea](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152501/how-to-add-a-custom-block-in-magento-2-system-configuration-group)

**The output**

[image: Yes]
[image: No]

Comment: Do you spent a lot of hours to obtain that? Why you could not be happy with the dropdown? Are you crazy :) +1 for your determination

Comment: I am getting this error.. 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'system/config/advance/check.phtml' in module: 'Vendor_Module' block's name: 'adminhtml\system\config\advanced_0'

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi where did you put your phtml file? can you show which path

Comment: it should be under `view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/advance/check.phtml`

Comment: Yes, the path was not correct, now template is detected but toggle is not coming in System configuration page. Output is https://paste.pics/c528ac1adbbfaa385c81b4f9a912e6db

Comment: did you run upgrade and redeploy static view files?

Comment: @AjwadTaqvi I forgot, you should indicate the field type in system.xml which is `type="checkbox"` check updated answer. kindly upvote if it helped you

Comment: @magefms I run upgrade and s:s:d also c:f added filed type. Complete field is <field id="status" translate="label" type="checkbox" sortOrder="104" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Advanced</frontend_model>
                <attribute type="shared">1</attribute>
                </field> but still same output as in SS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92819/discussion-between-magefms-and-ajwad-taqvi).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this code in your `system.xml`

```
...
<field id="enable_product" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
    <label>Enable Product</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
...
```

For a full example take a look at `system.xml` of a mine extension [here](https://github.com/LucScu/stock-status-label/blob/master/etc/adminhtml/system.xml).

Comment: I have updated the question with your answer and inserted the output. kindly check

Comment: I need a toggle switch like in the first image.

Comment: ok, i understand now...i think is not possible, i don't found anything like you need in the core, every enable settings are with dropdown. Why don't you use a dropdown, but you need a switch?

Comment: a switch is a toggle it is better to use than selecting an option using dropdown.

Comment: i'm agree, but all magento core enable settings are with dropdown, so i think that is is not very useful to invest time to create this new feature, better to wait for it to be released by the magento team or open a new thread here https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Feature-Requests-and/idb -p / feature-requests

Comment: It's okay. I have resolve it already by creating a custom block and assigned it in system config using frontend model element in system config

Comment: Great! Please write the answer and close the question.

Comment: okay I'll be posting it.